# input / button elements not shrinking in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When using input and button elements inside a flex container, the `flex` and/or `flex-grow` properties don't seem to do anything.

Code that demonstrates my issue.

```css
button,
input {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #EEE;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.inputrow {
  width: 30rem;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -.25rem;
}

.inputrow>* {
  margin: 0 .25rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 1.75rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nickname {
  flex: 1;
}

.message {
  flex: 4;
}

.s-button {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputrow">
  <input type="text" class="nickname" placeholder="Nickname">
  <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Message">
  <button type="submit" class="s-button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Code that shows what I'm expecting. *(using DIVs instead of `input` and `button`)*.

```css
.inputrow {
  width: 30rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin: 0 -.25rem;
}

.inputrow>* {
  margin: 0 .25rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
}

.nickname {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.message {
  flex: 4;
  background-color: red;
}

.s-button {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputrow">
  <div class="nickname">Nickname</div>
  <div class="message">Message</div>
  <div class="s-button">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting the background color of the inputs. If it works, will explain.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

An `input` element, unlike a `div`, comes with a default width.

Here's a simple illustration of this setting:

[image]

The browser automatically gives the `input` a width.

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input>
  <br><br>
  <div></div>
</form>
```

Also, an initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. This means that items cannot shrink below their width on the main axis.

Hence, `input` elements cannot shrink below their default width and may be forced to overflow the flex container.

You can override this behavior by setting your inputs to `min-width: 0` ([revised codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZYZyO))

Here's a full explanation: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

In some cases, you may need to override input widths using `width: 100%` or `width: 0`.

Comment: min-width thats it! :D

Comment: For me, this didn't do it: https://jsbin.com/danaworohe/edit?html,css,output compared to using only divs: https://jsbin.com/xilubuwora/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Finally, using only ```width: 0``` for the input itself solved this issue. No need for ```min-width: 0``` in my example: https://jsbin.com/dokataxupa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I also had to put `size="5"` on my `input`s as my browser seemed to be ensuring the default value of at least 20 characters was visible, despite `min-width: 0` and `flex-shrink: 1`.

Comment: `width: 100% || 0` worked for me here, however min-width: 0 don't. I guess that `[min || max]-width` and `width` itself has a primary character on the element sizing. Flex comes after and, based upon theis values, adds its characteristics to give flexbility and so on. The strange thing is that `flex-basis` doesn't has any prevalence over the width in this case, and in some others, it has. [CSS is Awe]some... lol

Comment: the issue is that you need to set `width: 0`, but then it doesnt behave as if its `width: auto`... [here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/NQNPEm)

Comment: Use `min-width: 0` to get it to shrink as necessary. Use `width: 100%` to get it to grow as necessary.

Comment: i just tested min-width:0 is not enough, i need to put width:100% as well, but anyw i solved my problem

Comment: Setting the width kind of defeats the whole flex purpose... This doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 12):

I needed to wrap the input element with a styled element and than set the input `width` and `min-width` as below:

```css
.field__input input {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have an input element inside a flex box, you can define `width: 0` and still can utilize `flex: 1` or whatever value you need.

This is [Christof Kälin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421361/input-button-elements-not-shrinking-in-a-flex-container#comment80372845_42421490) in the comments for another answer. Putting it here for visibility.

```js
const
  setValue = (btn, amount) => {
    const input = btn.closest('.stepper').querySelector('.stepper-val');
    input.value = +input.value + amount;
  },
  handleDecr = e => setValue(e.target, -1),
  handleIncr = e => setValue(e.target, 1);

document.querySelectorAll('.stepper').forEach(s => {
  s.querySelector('.stepper-minus').addEventListener('click', handleDecr);
  s.querySelector('.stepper-plus').addEventListener('click', handleIncr);
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /* font-size: 3vw; */
}

html, body, div, button, input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#atf {
  height: 100vh;
  /* flex-container */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.stepper {
  /* flex-container */
  display: flex;
  /* formatting */
  width: 12rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

.stepper-minus {
  /* flex-item */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* flex-container */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* formatting */
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: .6rem 0 0 .6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stepper-val {
  /* flex-item */
  flex-grow: 2;
  /* flex-container */
  text-align: center;
  /* formatting */
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  width: 0;
}

.stepper-plus {
  /* flex-item */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* flex-container */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* formatting */
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 0 .6rem .6rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stepper>button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="atf">
  <div class="stepper">
    <button class="stepper-minus">&minus;</button>
    <input class="stepper-val" type="text" name="val" value="32">
    <button class="stepper-plus">&plus;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Making this answer a community wiki so that I don't get unearned credit.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to extend [@Michael Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42421490/6904888) solution

> In some cases, you may need to override input widths using `width: 100%` or `width: 0`.

you can also do `calc(100%)`

Comment: How is it any different from `width: 100%`?

Answer (score 1):

if the parent is a flexible container set with the usual `flex: 1` (`flex-grow: 1`) and you want the input to shrink with the parent, this is what has worked for me:

```
width: 35px;
flex: 1 2 0px;
```

Give this as a class to the input, this will make it take the whole space when its available, but shrink to minimum size when resized.

**Edit:**

This works because it's a shorthand for `flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>` as explained here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flex

The '2' is assigned to `flex-shrink` which makes the element shrink.
Sometimes you still need to add `min-width: 0;` as mentioned in other comments to remove the `min-width` defined by browsers (for small containers)

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-basis: 0;` for `input` or `input container`  solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work in Edge.

Comment: @cgatian I don't have any idea

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting the width to 100% or what ever percentage you want but you should set it. That works for me.