# flex not respected by Input why?

Tags: css, flexbox, html-input

I've noticed the 'input' element does not stretch or shrink to fill a flex container. Does anyone know why and if there is a solution?

My example below shows the container class **c** being used on Div elements (which stretch properly). And a single class **e**, used for the right-justified fixed-length end. The row of divs stretch and shrink as expected, the row of inputs do not.

```css
div.c {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: stretch;
}

div.d {
  flex: 1;
}

div.e {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='c'>
  <div class='d'>A</div>
  <div class='d'>B</div>
  <div class='d'>C</div>
  <div class='d'>D</div>
  <div class='e'>E</div>
</div>

<div class='c'>
  <input class='d'></input>
  <input class='d'></input>
  <input class='d'></input>
  <input class='d'></input>
  <div class='e'></div>
</div>
```

**note** i am aware of this link:

[input / button elements not respecting flex-grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421361/input-button-elements-not-respecting-flex-grow)

However using min-width: 0; box-sizing: border-box; has no effect for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you specified `div.d` not `input.d` or `div .d` or just `.d`. Also, no need to close the `input` tag.

```css
div.c {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.d {
  flex: 1;
}

div.e {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='c'>
  <div class='d'>A</div>
  <div class='d'>B</div>
  <div class='d'>C</div>
  <div class='d'>D</div>
  <div class='e'>E</div>
</div>

<div class='c'>
  <input class='d'>
  <input class='d'>
  <input class='d'>
  <input class='d'>
  <div class='e'></div>
</div>
```