# Get form to respect flexbox parent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `form` with a single `input` tag sitting inside of a `div`. I'm trying to have the `form`/`input` respect the width of the parent, but I can't seem to make it react to flexbox -- it just decides its own width and overflows the container.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
  <form>
    <input value="baz"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex; 
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/331vgepu/).

What I would expect is that the flexbox setting on the parent div would shrink the form to fit inside of its width, but this isn't happening. Instead, the `form`/`input` just sits at its desired width and doesn't shrink down, even if I set `flex-shrink` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
form input{
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
  <form>
    <input value="baz">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work... but can you explain what's going on? Why do I need to set the form to grow when I want it to shrink? It seems like your code works without the flex-grow being set, too?

Comment: Also, from what I'm reading about `box-sizing` all it controls is whether padding and margin are included in size calculations, but the margin and padding take up almost no space so I don't understand why this works?

Comment: the flex-grow maybe was a mistake, I was testing, but without the box-sizing the padding make the input to becomes bigger, and the flexbox dont consider the padding width, so it doesn't ajust

Comment: OK -- it seems like just having `width: 100%` and `box-sizing: border-box` on the `input` tag is enough. Don't need to apply `box-sizing` to everything. If you're able to adjust your answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yeas, ajusted, but I'd recommend you to use box-sizing in all elements

Answer (score 2):

If you add this rule, the `input` will adjust.

```
.container input {
  width: 100%;               /*  override its defalt width  */
  box-sizing: border-box;    /*  make border/padding size be
                                 included in the set width  */
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container input {
  width: 100%;               /*  override its defalt width  */
  box-sizing: border-box;    /*  make border/padding size be
                                 included in the set width  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
  <form>
    <input value="baz" />
  </form>
</div>
```

The reason is that a flex item (here the `form`) can't be smaller than its content, even if one allow it to shrink using `flex-shrink`.

In this case it is the `input`, which has a predefined width, hence force the `form` to size with it, where the solution is to override the `input`'s width.

Furthermore, as the `input` is not a flex item, the `form` is, it won't respond to flex item properties.

Flex container/flex items have a parent/child relation, and it is only the children that are flex items, not grandchildren.

Here is some more reading about flex containers/items and form elements:

- [input / button elements not re-sizing properly in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421361/input-button-elements-not-re-sizing-properly-in-a-flex-container)
- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size/36247448)
- [Proper use of flex properties when nesting flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840646/proper-use-of-flex-properties-when-nesting-flex-containers)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me where I could read up on what is or isn't a "flex item"? Is it only direct children of a flexbox that are "flex items", and that's why the input isn't treated as such?

Comment: @aardvarkk Added a note to my answer about flex items and their flex container.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks...updated my answer with those 2 links + 1 cover `min-width`