# How can I make an input element respect the dimensions of a grid container?

Tags: css, forms, css-grid

I have an `input` element, inside a CSS grid container. The container should be 100 pixels wide, with the `input` element taking up most of the space, and an `other-thing` taking up the remaining 24px. I am using `grid-template-columns` for this.

This works fine if I make the parent container 200px instead of 100px:

[image]

```css
.container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 24px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px; /* Try 100px */
  background-color: red;
}
```

And the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <input value="hello"/>
  <div class="other-thing">
    x
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I make the container 100px wide, the input suddenly refuses to shrink - so it overlaps the red container.

[image]

> I know `input` elements have a user stylesheet, but I can't see anything related to width or display there that I should be overriding.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/593b1sdy/1/)

How do I make the `input` only use the remaining space in the container, preferably using `grid-template-columns`?

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421361/input-button-elements-not-shrinking-in-a-flex-container

Comment: @Paulie_D different question, same answer (user agent stylesheet doesn't show everything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem, from a visual perspective, is `justify-content: center`.

Because your container is set to `width: 100px`, the grid item will center horizontally within that space, overflowing the container equally on both sides. This causes the left side to disappear off-screen, and become totally inaccessible (even via scroll).

[image]

*(For a full explanation of this behavior, see: [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276))*

When you switch to `width: 200px`, the container is given enough space to accommodate the grid items, so the overflow doesn't occur.

[image]

The quickest and easiest solution to this problem is to remove `justify-content: center`. It's pointless anyway because the container is smaller than the content, and you can't center content without free space in the container. So `justify-content` isn't doing anything.

[image]

If you want all grid items to fit inside the container, then add `min-width: 0` to the `input` element. This allows the `input` to shrink below the size of its content and its `min-width: auto` default.

[image]

*(For a full explanation of this behavior, see: [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276))*

```css
.container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 24px;
  display: grid;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input value="hello" />
  <div class="other-thing">x</div>
</div>
```

*Note that the default width and minimum width of `input` elements used to be easy to see via Chrome / Firefox inspector tools. This appears to no longer be the case. I couldn't find the settings in user agent styles. We have to look at computed values for guidance or just assume there are width and min-width settings.*

Answer (score 4):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 24px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

input {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input value="hello" />
  <div class="other-thing">
    x
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but I don't know why - the user agent stylesheet doesn't show a value for `min-width`.

Comment: However, the computed tab does show `min-width:auto`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the input tag has it's own preferred, default width. It forces the grid to adapt to it.

You can solve the problem by specifying its size. For this situation, you want the element to fit to the size of its parent container (the grid cell).

```
input{
width:100%;
}
```

Will do the job. Each of your input tags will size themselves to fit your grid cell container.