# CSS Grid inconsistent formatting when a top level item is not a div

Tags: css, css-grid

what is the reason that a CSS Grid layout is rendered differently when a top level child item is an input rather than a div? and how could I resolve this so that they are rendered consistently?

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.container > * {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 5;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 6;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 7 / span 4;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 11 / span 1;
}
```

CSS Grid with divs as children:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item-3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item-4">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS Grid with one child instead as an input:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <input type="text" class="item-3" value="item 3" />
  <div class="item-4">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42421361/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always define the size explicitely otherwise the auto size will do the job and an input is not the same as a div

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /* the size of 1 column */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.container>* {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 5;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-column: 6;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-column: 7 / span 4;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-column: 11 / span 1;
}
```

```html
CSS Grid with divs as children:

<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item-3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item-4">Item 4</div>
</div>
CSS Grid with one child instead as an input:

<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <input type="text" class="item-3" value="item 3" />
  <div class="item-4">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, great catch, thanks for the explanation, @Temani Afif, I did not realise I had overlooked that