# Can't fit a 30px width button in this flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling way more than I should with this. I can't fit a 30x30px `<button>` in this `flex` container; it's overflowing over the red border. My attempts so far have been with making sure the button is properly set, but maybe it's related to the input taking a default width that `flex` just ignores.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
}

button {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  height: 30px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <input type="text">
    <button>X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `min-width: 10px;` (or whatever value you want that's small) to the input field.

The `<input>` has a default `size: 20;`. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#size)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 10px;
}

button {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  height: 30px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <input type="text">
    <button>X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! found a full explanation on this post as well, seems like input comes with a default width.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421361/input-button-elements-not-shrinking-in-a-flex-container